# In my form i am getting dynamic ids for textarea ,how to get value of textarea in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("[id$='SendMessage_MyBizForm_btnOK']").click(function () {
        var tovalue=$("#hdntoid").val();
        var fromvalue = $("#hdnfromvalue").val();
        var messagecontent = $("[id$='txtText']").val();
        var captcha = $("[id$='recaptcha_response_field']").val();
        debugger;
        if (messagecontent != "" && captcha != "") {
            Insertdatatinbox(tovalue, fromvalue, messagecontent, 0, 0);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: how many textareas do you have?

Comment: i am getting dynamically

Comment: @siri.p how  you getting dynamically. post the code where u appending the textareas. then only we can able to help u

Comment: which variable is textarea ?   `messagecontent`

Comment: yeah,messagecontent is variable of textarea

Comment: The selector of jquery you are using it will return collection of elements but when u use `.val();` it will return first element value. so which element value you want to get or if u need multiple so use loop to get value of each element

Comment: I want current textarea value...thanks for your replys

Comment: can you post dummy html to see how you want result